# Oracle Move from 9 to 11

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle9i

I have an oracle 9 database. There is a requirement to move this to Oracle 11.

What is the best way to achieve this. Is it enough to export the database on 9 and import it again on 11 or is there an upgrade process that can be gone through?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are choices here. Check out the [Oracle Documentation Upgrade Guide](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17222/toc.htm) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

How big is your data and how many schemas?  Doing the export/import can be a lot faster for smaller databases and gives you a chance to cleanup old users and re-organize tablespaces.  It's not very practical for a large database like an E-Business Suite install although I had to do that once because I was going from big-endian to little-endian hardware.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515532/porting-an-application-from-oracle-9-to-oracle-11-gottchas